# VideoCapture return wrong capture

Tags: c++, opencv

I using opencv library with c++, when i reading frame from two stream, some time (when noise exist) `cv::VideoCapture` return camera1 frame instead camera2, thanks for any idea.

```
class camera {
 public:
 cv::VideoCapture cap;

 bool open(const cv::String &filename)
 {
   cap.open(filename, cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
 }
 void read(cv::UMat &frame)
 {
   Mat fr;
   cap >> fr;
   if(!fr.empty())
   {
     frame = fr;
   }
 }
}
```

and main method of program :

```
int main()
{
 namedWindow("camera1");
 namedWindow("camera2");

 camera camera1;
 camera camera2;

 camera1.open("rtsp://192.168.1.2/test");
 camera2.open("rtsp://192.168.1.2/test2");

 while(true)
 {
  Mat frame1;
  Mat frame2;

  camera1.read(frame1);
  camera2.read(frame2);

  imshow("camera1", frame1);
  imshow("camera2", frame2);
  waitkey(30);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can say only one thing. In my own experience OpenCV VideoCapture class works with FFMPEG in on-line mode very badly. There was a lot of image artifacts and ffmpeg internal errors. But VideoCapture perfectly works with directshow-compatible USB cameras. I solved problem with on-line capture from IP-camera with XSplit Broadcaster. This package is able to emulate a USB-camera via physical IP-camera. Basic license of XSplit Broadcaster is absolutely free

Comment: Thanks alot, bot i working on windows and directshow isn't compatible  with windows.

Comment: DirectShow is a part of DirectX. DirectX is a part of windows. You don't need to work with DirectShow. XSplit Broadcaster will do all the job for you. I've already tested this configuration on Windows 7 64

Comment: Thanks so much  my friend, i tested XSplit Broadcaster program, works good, but i need open source program for using in my project.